# Sending a GET request on a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, request, get

I am trying to send a GET request to this URL: https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client
from a chrome extension.
When I use curl to send the request from my cmd, I get a valid JSON request. However when I send the same GET request throught the chrome extension, I get Error: HTTP error 400.

This is my code

```
function calc(lat, long) {
  fetch(`https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${long}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
      } else {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
    });
}
```

I read that you have to set permission in manifest.json. I have done that too

```
"host_permissions": [
      "https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/*"
  ]
```

Comment: Assuming you clicked the reload button in chrome://extensions after editing manifest.json, it sounds like you make the request in a content script? In that case you need to do it in the background script or in the action popup script.